# R Shiny's prettyRadioButtons answer options don't wrap based on screen size

Tags: r, shiny, responsive-design

Why do the long answer options of this `prettyRadioButtons` question not automatically wrap based on the screen size? Below are two screenshots of the Chrome browser's Inspect mode simulating different devices.

Even manually setting the width to "300px" doesn't wrap the answer options.

Chrome > Inspect > Responsive
[image]

Chrome > Inspect > iPhone SE
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 5, "font-scale" = 1.0), 
  
  div(class = "container-fluid",
      
      div(class = "row",
          div(class="col-12", 
              prettyRadioButtons(
                inputId = "a",
                label = "Group A",
                selected = NULL,
                status = "primary",
                shape = c("round"),
                width = NULL,
                choiceNames = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the ",
                                "printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum has",
                                "been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer"), 
                choiceValues = c("opt1", "opt2", "opt3")
              )
          )
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hmm not cool. I tried to change the CSS to wrap, but this totally destroyed the layout.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with Chrome. If Inspect opens with `Dimensions:` set to `Responsive` and then I switch to iPhone SE it works.

If Inspect opens with `Dimensions:` set to `iPhone SE` the answer options will always be cutoff.